# table view get slower while image adding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have added an image in table view cell fetching from the array. Image  shown in the table view cell correctly. But, while I am scrolling the table view its get slower and stuck. help me in coding.

```
NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.progolmexico.com/static/logo/%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] valueForKey:@"team_logo"]];
 NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  UIImage *cachedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.pteam.image = cachedImage;
```

Comment: When is this code used? In tableView: willDisplayCell:l forRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: This is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490259/uiimageviewafnetworking-setimagewithurlrequest-uses-restkit

Comment: use asynchronous download method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.progolmexico.com/static/logo/%@",[[array   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] valueForKey:@"team_logo"]];
     NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
     UIImage *cachedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     cell.pteam.image = cachedImage;
    });
});
```